# How to count subqueries in HQL?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, hql

I need to count this subquery with HQL ( using Hibernate in JPA )

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.customerName, s.customerCode, MAX(s.orderDate) as last_order_date 
FROM XoopsSalesOrder s 
GROUP BY s.customerCode 
HAVING MAX(s.orderDate) 
BETWEEN '2012-7-1' AND '2012-10-1' AND MAX(s.orderDate) NOT BETWEEN '2012-10-1' AND CURRENT_DATE "
```

I didn't use Hibernate lib , so I have to find away to count with HQL only.
Could anyone help me? Many thanks in advance !

Comment: Did you find a way in the end without drawing the full resultset?

Answer (score 0):

maybe  should ask for more details before answering your question but it seems i don't have enough points here (or reputation) to do that like others. Any way, the below is my idea.

Assume there is XoopsSalesOrder.Id as primary key and XoopsSalesOrder.customerCode is unique.

```
select s.customerName, s.customerCode, s.orderDate as last_order_date 
from XoopsSalesOrder s 
where s.Id in (
  select s2.Id from XoopsSalesOrder s2 
  where 
  s2.orderDate = max(s2.orderDate) 
  and s2.orderDate between '2012-7-1' AND '2012-10-1' 
  and s2.orderDate not between '2012-10-1' AND current_date 
  group by s2.customerCode
)
```